# How to count results of file names from a matched regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex, filesystems, counting

I'm trying to use a regex to match parts of the names of a file type, then count the amount of results that match and display those.
For example, if the regular expression is looking for filenames with the words "germany" in them and theres 5 files with "germany" in them, i want to be able to count those matches out of a total number and say "You have 5 germany mentions"

Ive set a path to the directory to count from and have managed to get a matching regex to at least one type (I want to do this for multiple expressions.) and counting through them with a foreach using the file extension.

````cs
public static void russianBias()
        {
            int x = 0;
            string[] replayslol = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Games\World_of_Tanks\replays", "*.wotreplay");
            foreach (string file in replayslol)
            {
                string replayresult = string.Concat(replayslol);
                Regex russia = new Regex(@"_ussr-");
                foreach (Match match in russia.Matches(replayresult))
                {
                    x++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("You've played Russian vehicles {0}" + x + " times!");
            //repeat for all nations
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close.");
            Console.ReadLine();```

The goal is to have this say a number of times for every nation in this game.
The issue is that the regex does not seem to quite match the filenames and actually matches too many items.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Directory.GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8) will return a `String[]` When you use [String.Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.concat?view=netframework-4.8) on that array, you will create a string out of all the strings in the array.

Counting the matches this way is not reliable when the pattern can occur multiple times in the string. Note that you also use 2 times a `foreach` and perform the count over all concatenated strings.

I think you could just check if the filename only matches the pattern and then increment the counter.

The pattern you specify as the regex `_ussr-` can also just be a string in this case. If you only want to check if a string occurs in the filename, you could use [String.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.8) instead.

If you do want to use a regex, you could replace the call to `file.Contains` with [Regex.IsMatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch?view=netframework-4.8) which will also return a Boolean.

For example:

```
int russiaCount = 0;
int germanyCount = 0;
string[] replayslol = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"./replays", "*.wotreplay");
foreach (string file in replayslol)
{
    if (file.Contains("_ussr-")) {
        russiaCount++;
    }
    if (file.Contains("_germany-")) {
        germanyCount++;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("You've played Russian vehicles {0} times and German vehicles {1} times!", russiaCount, germanyCount);
```

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/ZE74Mj)

Comment: This worked beautifully, thank you. Didnt know file.Contains was a thing! useful to know lol

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that maybe an expression that'd check for `Germany` might work, with an `i` flag, then you'd just add a counter, if returned `true`:

```
^(?=.*\bgermany\b).*$
```

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"^(?=.*\bgermany\b).*$";
        string input = @"some data germany some other data
some data Germany some other data
some data GERMANY some other data
some data France some other data
some data UK some other data";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/1yPlhR/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/1yPlhR/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---